# WPF Datagrid resize when autogenerateColumns is set to true

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid on which `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to true (the `Columns` are dynamically generated) and I have set the `HorizontalAlignment` to `Left`, to get rid of the extra `Column` on the right.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="myTemplate">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="name" Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <TextBlock Text="name1" Margin="20,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <SelectiveScrollingGrid Grid.Row="2">
      <DataGrid x:Name="ProcessParameterGrid"
                AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BindingProp}"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="20,0,0,10"
                CanUserSortColumns="False"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                HeadersVisibility="Column"
                FrozenColumnCount="1"/>
    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
  </Grid>
</DataTemplate>`

<ScrollViewer>
  <CustomPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecipeDetailsCollectionViewSource}}"
                  VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"
                          ContentTemplate="{StaticResource myTemplate}"
                          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
  </CustomPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**The problem:**
I need the first `Column` of the `Grid` to freeze and I need the `DataGrid` to resize with the parent container - the `Grid`. 
If I set the `Width` for the `DataGrid` explicitly, the extra `Column` on right shows up. What am I missing?